# How to delete gem from rubygem.org?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to completely delete my gem from rubygem.org. 
I browsed the dashboard, but there is no delete button.
How can I delete it?

Comment: From the documentation: http://help.rubygems.org/kb/gemcutter/removing-a-published-rubygem

Answer (score 6):

Thank you. Sid.
I solved it.

```
# install gemcutter
gem install gemcutter

gem yank yourgemname -v 0.0.1
gem yank yourgemname -v 0.0.2
gem yank yourgemname -v 0.0.3
```

Comment: `gem yank yourgemname -v 0.1.0 --host https://rubygems.org`, This could also help someone in the future.

Comment: `gem yank GEM -v VERSION [-p PLATFORM] [--key KEY_NAME] [--host HOST]`